# How to get points (latitude and longitude) between two point (Point A and Point B) in PostGIS?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, postgis, openstreetmap

A am using PostGIS (OSM), and I don't have a solution how to get points with locations (latitude and longitude) between two point (Point A and Point B). I know about ST_Distance function, but this function does not return point with location, this function only calculate distance between points. How can I get points with locations?[image]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the points you want to retrieve are locations along a road (linestring) you can split the linestring between the two points and then select the points that overlap or are close to it.

Consider these points and linestring, respectively stored in tables `points` and `line`:

[image]

You can use the function [`ST_LineLocatePoint`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_LineLocatePoint.html) to get the exact location of a given point in the line, and with these locations you can *cut* the linestring into a subset using [`ST_LineSubstring`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_LineSubstring.html). With this subset you can check which points intersect or are close to it. The following example retrieves the points along the line that are between `POINT(-4.71 54.12)` and `POINT(-4.53 54.21)` - second and previous last points:

```
SELECT points.geom
FROM line
JOIN points ON 
  ST_Intersects(
    points.geom,
    ST_LineSubstring(
     line.geom,
     ST_LineLocatePoint(line.geom,'SRID=4326;POINT(-4.71 54.12)'::geometry),
     ST_LineLocatePoint(line.geom,'SRID=4326;POINT(-4.53 54.21)'::geometry)))
```

[image]

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=32fa1e3f2da63e6f769540a72a844544)

Comment: This code with my tables not working. I have these tables : planet_osm_line, planet_osm_point, planet_osm_polygon, planet_osm_roads, spatial_ref_sys. I renamed tables name in sql code, but that code still not working, Error: SQL Error [XX000]: ERROR: LWGEOM_line_locate_point: Operation on mixed SRID geometries (LineString, 3857) != (Point, 4326)

Comment: SELECT 
  ST_AsText(planet_osm_point.way)
FROM planet_osm_line
JOIN planet_osm_point ON 
  ST_Intersects(planet_osm_point.way,
    ST_LineSubstring(
     planet_osm_line.way,
     ST_LineLocatePoint(planet_osm_line.way,'SRID=4326;POINT(41.574449 60.604039)'::geometry),
     ST_LineLocatePoint(planet_osm_line.way,'SRID=4326;POINT(41.554493 60.599424)'::geometry)));

Comment: @TakhirAtamuratov It is not working because you're mixing different SRS (4326 AND 3857) stick to one of them while processing.

Comment: What SRID should I use to get correct points with location? With SRID=4326 I get exception, with SRID=3857 I get the next parameters, I think they are not locations POINT(7381341.7930422 4662469.03295133)
POINT(7381380.59901669 4662627.87924187)
POINT(7381380.59901669 4662627.87924187)
POINT(7380389.79988888 4661831.66459254)
POINT(7378260.3025578 4656745.9033563)
POINT(7379854.14163114 4660894.71678399)
POINT(7380301.38994929 4661624.78510236)
POINT(7383469.35341414 4670214.98696365)

Comment: @TakhirAtamuratov you have to transform them to 4326. Take a look at `ST_Transform`